# composing password hash functions

Tags: hash, password-hashing, preimage-resistance

Firstly I know that what I'm asking about is not practical, so let's keep it theoretical.

Let $B[H](x)$ be balloon hashing with $H$ as it's underlying hash.
What happens if I do $B[H1](B[H2](x))$, where $H1, H2$ are distinct hash functions based on different construction, let's say **blake2b** and **sha3**?

Where do I lose security, and where do I gain it?

My intuition is that there should be benefit in preimage resistance, and in case one of underlying hashes is compromised.